# strip(char) on a string

Tags: python, string, strip

I am trying to strip the characters '_ ' (underscore and space) away from my string. The first code fails to strip anything.

The code for word_1 works just as I intend. Could anyone enlighten me how to modify the first code to get output 'ale'?

```
word = 'a_ _ le' 

word.strip('_ ')

word_1 = '_ _ le'
word_1.strip('_ ')
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `replace()` in this use case, not `strip()`

```
word.replace('_ ', '')
```

`strip()`:

> string.strip(s[, chars])
>
> > Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this method is called on.

`replace()`:

> string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
>
> > Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

[Strings in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Answer (score 2):

`.strip` removes the target string from the start and end of the source string.

You want `.replace`.

```
>>> word = 'a_ _ le'
>>> word = word.replace("_ ", "")
>>> word
'ale'
```

Answer (score 0):

`.strip()` is used when the passed string has to be removed from the start and end of string. It does not work in the middle. For this, `.replace()` is used as `word.replace('_ ', '')`. This outputs `ale`